# Why does AudioSegment outputs an incomplete audio file?

Tags: python, django, audio

I am running a Django application and in one of my views, I receive an audio file sent via POST. I save it as a temp file in the following way

```
def save_temp_file(temp_file, filename):                                        
    with open('/tmp/uploads/{0}'.format(filename), 'wb+') as destination:
       for chunk in temp_file.chunks():                                        
          destination.write(chunk)                                            
    destination.close()
```

Then I convert the .webm received to .mp3 format using the following function

```
from pydub import AudioSegment                                                                           
def convert_wav_ogg(filename):                                                                           
    file_path = "/tmp/uploads/" + filename                                                        
    AudioSegment.from_file(file_path).export('/tmp/uploads/{}.mp3'.format(filename), format='mp3')
    return "{0}.mp3".format(filename)
```

The problem I get is that the output file sometimes get cut in the middle.
For instance, the audio plays correctly from 0:00 to 0:05 and then cuts to 0:15. It's really weird and there doesn't seem to have any pattern to it.

The problem only seems to happen in the production environment, and if I run the exact same lines of code in the Python interactive console over the same files, the output is correct.

Any clues to why that is?

I'm running:

```
daphne==2.5.0
Django==2.2.14
pydub==0.24.1
```

Comment: did you check if you get full `.webm` ?

Comment: I checked and the .webm is fine.